# Querying an XML file

Tags: c#, xml, ravendb

Good morning
I am trying to create an application that will accept an XML file and import selected data in a Raven database.

I have the following XML file:
    This is a sample of the XML Code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PROJECTS xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<row>
<APPLICATION_ID>8524889</APPLICATION_ID>
<ACTIVITY>F30</ACTIVITY>
<ADMINISTERING_IC>DK</ADMINISTERING_IC>
<APPLICATION_TYPE>1</APPLICATION_TYPE>
<ARRA_FUNDED>N</ARRA_FUNDED>
<BUDGET_START>06/24/2013</BUDGET_START>
<BUDGET_END>06/23/2014</BUDGET_END>
<FOA_NUMBER>PA-11-110</FOA_NUMBER>
<FULL_PROJECT_NUM>1F30DK099017-01</FULL_PROJECT_NUM>
<FUNDING_ICs>NIDDK:32342\</FUNDING_ICs>
<FY>2013</FY>
<NIH_SPENDING_CATS xsi:nil="true"/>
<ORG_CITY>STANFORD</ORG_CITY>
<ORG_COUNTRY>UNITED STATES</ORG_COUNTRY>
<ORG_DISTRICT>18</ORG_DISTRICT>
<ORG_DUNS>009214214</ORG_DUNS>
<ORG_DEPT>MICROBIOLOGY/IMMUN/VIROLOGY</ORG_DEPT>
<ORG_FIPS>US</ORG_FIPS>
<ORG_STATE>CA</ORG_STATE>
<ORG_ZIPCODE>943056203</ORG_ZIPCODE>
<IC_NAME>NATIONAL INSTITUTE OF DIABETES AND DIGESTIVE AND KIDNEY DISEASES</IC_NAME>
<ORG_NAME>STANFORD UNIVERSITY</ORG_NAME>
<PIS><PI><PI_NAME>PHAM, EDWARD ANHOA</PI_NAME><PI_ID>11461179</PI_ID></PI></PIS>
<PROJECT_TERMSX><TERM>5&apos;Untranslated Regions</TERM><TERM>Acylation</TERM><TERM>Adverse effects</TERM><TERM>Affect</TERM><TERM>anti-hepatitis C</TERM><TERM>Antiviral Agents</TERM><TERM>base</TERM><TERM>Beryllium</TERM><TERM>Binding (Molecular Function)</TERM><TERM>Biological</TERM><TERM>Biological Process</TERM><TERM>Cell Culture Techniques</TERM><TERM>Cells</TERM><TERM>Crystallography</TERM><TERM>Data</TERM><TERM>design</TERM><TERM>effective therapy</TERM><TERM>Elements</TERM><TERM>fluorophore</TERM><TERM>Foundations</TERM><TERM>Future</TERM><TERM>Genetic Transcription</TERM><TERM>Genome</TERM><TERM>Genomics</TERM><TERM>Goals</TERM><TERM>Gold</TERM><TERM>Hepatitis C virus</TERM><TERM>Hydroxyl Radical</TERM><TERM>Indium</TERM><TERM>Induced Mutation</TERM><TERM>Infection</TERM><TERM>Information Storage</TERM><TERM>inhibitor/antagonist</TERM><TERM>Lead</TERM><TERM>Life Cycle Stages</TERM><TERM>Liver</TERM><TERM>liver transplantation</TERM><TERM>Malignant neoplasm of liver</TERM><TERM>Maps</TERM><TERM>Mediating</TERM><TERM>Methods</TERM><TERM>Microfluidics</TERM><TERM>MicroRNAs</TERM><TERM>Modeling</TERM><TERM>Molecular Virology</TERM><TERM>Monitor</TERM><TERM>mutant</TERM><TERM>Mutation</TERM><TERM>Names</TERM><TERM>next generation</TERM><TERM>novel</TERM><TERM>Nuclear Magnetic Resonance</TERM><TERM>Nucleic Acid Regulatory Sequences</TERM><TERM>Patients</TERM><TERM>Pegylated Interferon Alfa</TERM><TERM>Play</TERM><TERM>Polymerase</TERM><TERM>Primer Extension</TERM><TERM>Proteins</TERM><TERM>Quartz</TERM><TERM>Regulatory Element</TERM><TERM>Research</TERM><TERM>Resistance</TERM><TERM>RNA</TERM><TERM>RNA Binding</TERM><TERM>RNA chemical synthesis</TERM><TERM>RNA Viruses</TERM><TERM>Role</TERM><TERM>screening</TERM><TERM>Site</TERM><TERM>small molecule</TERM><TERM>standard of care</TERM><TERM>Structure</TERM><TERM>Testing</TERM><TERM>therapeutic target</TERM><TERM>Time</TERM><TERM>tool</TERM><TERM>Translations</TERM><TERM>United States</TERM><TERM>Viral</TERM><TERM>Viral Proteins</TERM><TERM>viral RNA</TERM><TERM>Virus</TERM><TERM>Virus Replication</TERM></PROJECT_TERMSX>
<PROJECT_TITLE>Structure-function determination of the Hepatitis C Virus negative RNA strand???s</PROJECT_TITLE>
<PROJECT_START>06/24/2013</PROJECT_START>
<PROJECT_END>06/23/2016</PROJECT_END>
<PHR> Hepatitis C virus (HCV) is the most common cause of liver cancer and the leading indication for liver transplantation in the United States, both of which are preventable by more effectively treating the etiologic infection. Current standard of care (SOC) for HCV treatment is inadequate for many patients and associated with significant toxic side effects. The goal of this project is to determine the relevant RNA secondary structures of a key RNA regulatory element in the HCV life cycle, which can form the basis for novel antiviral strategies directed at targeting key RNA elements.</PHR>
<SERIAL_NUMBER>99017</SERIAL_NUMBER>
<STUDY_SECTION>ZDK1</STUDY_SECTION>
<STUDY_SECTION_NAME>Special Emphasis Panel</STUDY_SECTION_NAME>
<SUPPORT_YEAR>1</SUPPORT_YEAR>
<SUFFIX xsi:nil="true"/>
<SUBPROJECT_ID xsi:nil="true"/>
<TOTAL_COST>32342</TOTAL_COST>
<TOTAL_COST_SUB_PROJECT xsi:nil="true"/>
<CORE_PROJECT_NUM>F30DK099017</CORE_PROJECT_NUM>
<CFDA_CODE>847</CFDA_CODE>
<PROGRAM_OFFICER_NAME>PODSKALNY, JUDITH M,</PROGRAM_OFFICER_NAME>
<ED_INST_TYPE>SCHOOLS OF MEDICINE</ED_INST_TYPE>
<AWARD_NOTICE_DATE>04/19/2013</AWARD_NOTICE_DATE>
<FUNDING_MECHANISM>Training, Individual</FUNDING_MECHANISM>
</row>
</PROJECTS>
```

At the moment I query the xml file with the following code:

```
string fm = "Some Text";
var names = from info in XMLFile.Descendants("row")
            where info.Element("FUNDING_MECHANISM").Value == fm
            select new {
            // much more to be added...
            SN=info.Element("SERIAL_NUMBER").Value,
            ICName=info.Element("IC_NAME").Value,
            TotalCost=info.Element("TOTAL_COST").Value };
```

The thing is that I generically want the query to find all the tag names from the xml file and dynamically put them in the place of the SN, `ICName` and `TotalCost`.
This is because I want to give me all the names of the tags and its value, next to it and not only some of them.

I tried the following:

```
XMLFile.Element(Name) = fund_mech.Element(fund_mech.Name).Value
```

in the query but it does not work.

Tha output of the file at the moment is the following:

```
{ SN = 1769, ICName = NCI, TotalCost = 2824 }
{ SN = 1679, ICName = NCST, TotalCost = 1191 }
```

However, there are many more tags in the xml file that I would like to retrieve in an optimal way.

Can someone help?

Comment: Can you post the full XML or at least a complete section of it?

Comment: And your `where` statement will be filtering based on the value of `fm` so you could probably remove this if you want all elements

Comment: From the whole XML file I only want to retrieve the elements where fm=" "... but I want to be able to retrieve ALL tags of these elements with their values, at once,and not having to define each one element at a time, e.g. SERIAL_NUMBER, TOTAL_COST, etc.

Comment: Ok... You can use an [Xml Serializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) to create a poco from the XML which may be easier than your current approach. You can use the [xsd tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5s2x1sy7.aspx) to generate a class from your XML which will save you all the typing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what your end goal is, but you can use the xml to populate an ExpandoObject.

From MSDN:

**"Represents an object whose members can be dynamically added and removed at run time."**

```
        var x = new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string, Object>;
        string fm = "Training, Individual";

        var names = from info in XMLFile.Elements("PROJECTS").Elements("row")
                    where info.Element("FUNDING_MECHANISM").Value == fm
                    select info;

         x = GetExpandoForNodes(names.Descendants());

         foreach (string key in x.Keys)
         {
             Console.WriteLine("Key: {0}, Value: {1}", key, x[key]);
         }
         Console.ReadKey();
```

The recursive code below is a slight modification of the code found at https://gist.github.com/asoftwareguy/1064812. Changes were made to convert the element name to title case and remove the underscore, before saving it as a key. Also, where there were multiple sub-elements with the same name, the values were saved to a generic list of strings.

```
private static dynamic GetExpandoForNodes(IEnumerable<XElement> nodes)
    {            
        var config = new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string, Object>;
        foreach (XElement n in nodes)
        {
            if (n.Descendants().Count() == 0)
            {

                //create your property name from the xml tags, by converting to title-case and removing the underscore
                string propName = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(n.Name.ToString().ToLower()).Replace("_", "");

                var nodecount = from c in nodes
                                where c.Name == n.Name
                                select c;                    

                if (nodecount.Count() > 1)
                {
                    List<string> lst = new List<string>();
                    if ((config as IDictionary<String, object>).ContainsKey(propName))
                    {                            
                        lst = (List<string>)(config as IDictionary<String, object>)[propName];
                        lst.Add(n.Value.Trim());
                        (config as IDictionary<String, object>)[propName] = lst;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        (config as IDictionary<String, object>)[propName] = new List<string>() { n.Value.Trim() };
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    (config as IDictionary<String, object>)[propName] = n.Value.Trim();
                }              
            }
            else
            {
                dynamic child = GetExpandoForNodes(n.Descendants());                                        
            }
        }
        return config;
    }
```